# Measure: Conditional Count Previous Quarter returning blank

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('fSampleResultsOilWater'),
        FILTER(
            'fSampleResultsOilWater',
            'fSampleResultsOilWater'[Severity] IN {"Abnormal","Severe"}
        ),
        DATEADD(
            'dDates'[Date],
            -1,
            QUARTER
        )
     )
```

***Subsets of complete Data Model***

**'dDates'** *'dDates'[Date] : One-to-Many : 'fSampleResultsOilWater'[Diagnosis Date]*

| Date | Month Abbrev | Month Number | Quarter | Q Abbrev | Q Year | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/2/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/3/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/4/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/5/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/6/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/7/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/8/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/9/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/10/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/11/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/12/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/13/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/14/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/15/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/16/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/17/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/18/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/19/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/20/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/21/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/22/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/23/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/24/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/25/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/26/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/27/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/28/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/29/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/30/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |
| 1/31/2023 | Jan | 1 | 1 | 1Q | 1Q2023 | 2023 |

**'fSampleResultsOilWater'**

| Hull Number | Compartment Type | Severity | Diagnosis Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 206 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/2/2015 |
| 206 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/2/2015 |
| 206 | DIESEL ENGINE | Caution | 1/2/2015 |
| 212 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/2/2015 |
| 212 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/2/2015 |
| 212 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/2/2015 |
| 212 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/2/2015 |
| 215 | DIESEL ENGINE | Caution | 1/2/2015 |
| 215 | REDUCTION GEARBOX | Normal | 1/2/2015 |
| 1104 | REDUCTION GEARBOX | Abnormal | 1/2/2015 |
| 1104 | REDUCTION GEARBOX | Abnormal | 1/2/2015 |
| 10 | DIESEL ENGINE | Abnormal | 1/3/2015 |
| 10 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 10 | NEW OIL | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 109 | DIESEL ENGINE | Caution | 1/5/2015 |
| 207 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 207 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 207 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 210 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 210 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 210 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 210 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 210 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 210 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 210 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Normal | 1/5/2015 |
| 210 | HYDRAULIC SYSTEM | Abnormal | 1/5/2015 |
| 207 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/6/2015 |
| 207 | DIESEL ENGINE | Normal | 1/6/2015 |
| 207 | DIESEL ENGINE | Abnormal | 1/6/2015 |

Comment: Please share your input/expected output as well as your model.

Comment: Is your date table marked as a date table?